# Searching for lines with a specific word

Tags: python

I need to search for a **specific** word on each line. If I find it, put it into a list.

For example I have lines below and I'm looking for a string 'TTT'.

```
TTT   ogkgkgk   yyryryr
ghgh  TTTXXX    fgfgfgf
gfgf  ghghgTTT  fgfgf
```

Only the first line should match since it contains the exact word 'TTT'. If I use the following below, it will match the other two lines since both 'TTTXXX' and 'ghghgTTT' contain 'TTT'.

```
mystring = str([line for line in common.split('\n') if 'TTT' in line])
```

How do I only match the first line?

Answer (score 6):

Just change the `if` check in your list comprehension to `if 'TTT' in line.split()`:

```
[line for line in common.split('\n') if 'TTT' in line.split()]
```

This will split the line on whitespace so `'TTT' in line.split()` will only be true if `TTT` is separated from every other chunk of the line by at least one whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regex with word boundaries:

```
 import re
 mystring = str([line for line in common.split('\n') if re.search(r'\bTTT\b', line)])
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A regex should do the trick!

```
import re
mystring = str([line for line in common.split('\n') if re.search(r"^(.*\s)*TTT(\s.*)$", line)])
```